# Create Dynamic table on jsp for items in arraylist

Tags: jsp, dynamic, html-table, jstl

In my spring web application I have arraylist in model attribute which I want to show in table format in JSP. I need to arrange the list items in the two columns dynamically. Below is code which creates only one column but I need to arrange then in even odd pair in two columns.

```
 <table>
    <c:forEach items="${artifact.answerOptions}" var="answeroption" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
      <td>
      <form:radiobutton path="choosenAnswers" value="${answeroption}"/>
    <label for="choosenAnswers" class="lowerlabel"><c:out value="${answeroption.answerText}"/></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
   </table>
```

Here answerOptions is the list of AnswerOption beans which has answerText property.
Above code creates table but with one column, but I need them to arrange in even odd manner like below:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td> List Item 1</td>
     <td> List Item 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td> List Item 3</td>
     <td> List Item 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td> List Item 5</td>
     <td> List Item 6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `begin`, `end` and `step` attributes instead. You could let it iterate by 2 and get the list items by index directly.

```
<table>
  <c:forEach begin="0" end="${fn:length(artifact.answerOptions)}" step="2" varStatus="loop">
    <tr>
      <td>${artifact.answerOptions[loop.index]}</td>
      <td>${artifact.answerOptions[loop.index + 1]}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

*(no this doesn't throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you have odd amount of items)*

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not possible cause in iterator at a time you will have access to only one `answerOptions` object not 2 so you can not format it like this.

Comment: Is there another way to arrange list items in the manner shown above, like any taglib which will allow access to even odd elements in the list?

Comment: @Sunil: I'm not that much aware of tag libs so can't tell you properly that anything is available or not.